# Using python, how can I display a matrix of RGB values in a window?

Tags: python, pygame

I have calculated a matrix of RGB triples for an image and I would like to know the most straightforward technique to display them in an interactive window.  I suspect that pygame will be involved.  Techniques that minimize the use of `pip` will be given preference.

```
result = numpy.zeros([height,width, 3], dtype=numpy.uint8)
pyopencl.enqueue_copy(queue, result, result_g).wait()

surface = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
# now what?
```

Comment: check this question out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30818367/how-to-present-numpy-array-into-pygame-surface/30970504#30970504

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution I was able to get working was this:

```
result = numpy.zeros([height,width, 3], dtype=numpy.uint8)
pyopencl.enqueue_copy(queue, result, result_g).wait()

surface = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height), pygame.DOUBLEBUF)
rgb2 = numpy.transpose(rgb, (1,0,2))          
pygame.pixelcopy.array_to_surface(surface, rgb2)
pygame.display.flip()
```

The transpose is only necessary because my opencl kernel computed an image arranged as `result[y,x,:] = (r,g,b)` whereas array_to_surface expects `result[x,y,:]` (which is backwards from how most framebuffers work).  I could alter my opencl kernel to store things in column-major order if I wanted to avoid the transpose.

This solution only works because my surface is the exact same dimensions as my image.  I will upvote any other good solutions that work when the surface and the pixel matrix are different dimensions (because someone might find this article when searching for that).

Answer (score 0):

It is difficult to answer exactly without knowing what the code you have shown does, but something like this:

```
for c in range(width):
   for d in range(height):
      color = result(d,c)
      pygame.draw.line(surface, color, (c,d),(c+1,d))
```